# How to integration react-native app with android

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I am newbie of REact native and I want to make an application of React native with Andoid. For React-native, I passed some docs on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html......but on that, ther are not any tutorial about integration of both react native and android.

If anyone have tutorials about this or project sample (React native & android ). Please share to me !! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get started with react native using the official documentation. So follow the below steps:

1) Install react Native and other associated dependencies from [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

2) Follow [this](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html) tutorial to setup a simple hello world app

Thereafter, it just a matter of adding new screens, using components, navigating between screens, making network requests, etc, and you know what, all those can be found in the official documentation.

Comment: Ok, tks Zeddysoft. I did some example follow what you shared but I mean that : Do we need android code (Java) for react-native app ?

Comment: @IRIS you write react native apps using java script even though, you can write native code( java) when you need to optimize certain aspects of your app

Comment: Ok, I understand what you said but I mean how to interagrion frm react-native to java code (android) step by step

Answer (score 0):

based on my experience. Maybe you can try first to create some example in the official documentation. Follow this [**Getting Started** with **ReactNative**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html). And if you already know **How `ReactNative` works**
 ([Read this article](https://tadeuzagallo.com/blog/react-native-bridge/)), you can go on to create a native code to build your app. You can continue to follow this [**Intermediate Learn ReactNative** with **Native Modul**](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html).

I hope my answer can help you. Keep fighting!!

Comment: tks muhammadaa, I passed somw example on http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html......But I want to ask : Is it neccessary to code Android in react native app or just use component of react native.Next question is assume there is an application then I click on a button then an event occurs and call to android code, so how can I do that

Comment: ReactNative can be use native code in Android (java) and the native code can be use with component of ReactNative.. So,if you want to call the code with a button as an event, it is possible.. but first you must build a native code as component in ReactNative. 
I've included how you can understand in [this](https://tadeuzagallo.com/blog/react-native-bridge/).